# Months starting with monday for giving year

Tags: linux, date, ubuntu, count, command

So, i trying to figure out ; How many months start with monday (being day 1 of the month) in a giving year.

right now i got

```
cal 2021 | awk '{ print $2 $9 $16}'
```

which displays all the mondays. I need to get rid of a few horizontal lines
I tried a few variant of

```
cut
```

but it seems to only cut vertically.

Answer (score 0):

> How many months start with monday (being day 1 of the month) in a giving year

For this purpose, the `ncal` mode of output (with the Mondays linewise rather than columnwise) is better suited - we can simply grep for all Mondays, then grep for day 1, and count the occurrences:

```
ncal 2021|grep Mo|grep -o ' 1 '|wc -l
```

Comment: The thing with 
~~~
ncal 2021|grep Mo|grep -o ' 1 '|wc -l
~~~ 
You get all the ones.

Something closer would be 
~~~
(ncal -M -y YEAR | grep Mo | grep -c "1"
~~~

but for whatever reason, it shows 3 even for years that have 2.

Comment: Isn't to _get all the ones_ exactly what you asked for? Why do you think your variant would be _closer_? In fact, by omitting the spaces in the grep pattern, you introduced the error which causes always _3_ to be shown. Just copy and paste the command I gave, and if the output isn't correct, show it.